# Was any MiG-29 modernized to incorporate digital systems?

Tags: military, avionics, fighter, russia, mig-29

Did any air force using the MiG-29 ever modernize their aircraft so that they can fly on fully digital equipment such as the following?

1. Digital HUD
2. Digital fly-by-wire
3. Digital navigation system
4. Digital ...

IOW, from this

[image]
<sup>*Cold-war era Mig-29*</sup>

to this

[image]
<sup>*Mig-35*</sup>

Comment: According to WIkipedia (and others), the basic design included a digital computer. Can you describe what you mean by "digital equipment"?

Comment: The second picture isn't even from a MiG. It's from a Eurofighter Typhoon

Comment: I doubt that the OP wanted to spend hours and hours with a drawing program or 3D modeling program to make a realistic simulation of a MiG-29 with a glass cockpit just to make his or her point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, MiG-35 from your second picture *is*, to a large extent, a modernized version of MiG-29. All later versions of MiG-29, the so-called 9-15+: 29M, K, etc, including 35 itself, incorporate digital FBW and avionics.

If you are talking about upgrading the original 9-12 airframes, then, I'm afraid, only the avionics and radar can be changed to digital. The MiG-29SMT and UPG are such upgrades. Retrofitting a new control system (FBW) is problematic; this makes it a very different aircraft internally. Such job can only be done by the manufacturer, and it hardly makes much sense over ordering new MiG-35.

Answer (score 7):

[Yes, India has designed and installed their own home-grown digital cockpit upgrades for their MIG-29's.](https://defence.pk/pdf/threads/indias-ingeniously-modernized-mig-29-flies.364783/)

Comment: Except it's not home-grown, it's mostly Israeli and French.

Comment: @Zeus - it's "home grown" in that it wasn't developed and supplied by MiG, but your point is valid...

Answer (score 3):

**Land-based Mig29s:**
Many Indian (69 nos.) and some Russian, Egyptian and Syrian Mig29s are upgraded to 'SMT' standard that includes upgraded mission computer, glass cockpit, HUD, digital fly-by-wire, Zhuk-ME radar, increased range to 2,100km, in-flight refueling, among others. The basic objective of this upgrade was to improve range and make this a 'true multirole' combat platform that enables it to compete with the likes of Saab Gripen & F16. Indian upgraded Mig29s are essentially same as Russian ones, except they have home-grown EW suite & French Topsight-I helmet mounted display sight.
[image]
Source combataircraft.net

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWhhK.jpg):[image] https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ip89p.jpg

**Carrier-based Mig29s:**
Carrier-based Fulcrums are nearly identical to shore-based ones, except they have strengthened undercarriage & landing-gear to sustain carrier landings, plus larger horizontal stabilizer to improve low-speed performance. In addition, they have larger payload of 5.5 tons (versus 4.5 tons in shore-based Mig29s). India currently has 36 nos. of these and Russia has about 20 of these.
[image]

Comment: That's great information!